# avoid cyclic dependency when defining an ecs service with loadbalancer listener in AWS-CDK

Tags: python-3.x, aws-cdk

I have two (and several other) stacks which create a cyclic dependency:

- app.py

```
app = cdk.App()
vpc_stack = RcsVpcStack(app, "RcsVPCStack")
efs_stack = RcsEfsStack(app, "RcsEfsStack", vpc_stack=vpc_stack)
ecs_stack = RcsECSStack(app, "RcsECSStack", vpc_stack=vpc_stack, fileSystem=efs_stack.efs_filesystem)

elbv2_stack = RcsELBv2Stack(app, "RcsELBv2Stack", 
                            vpc_stack=vpc_stack,  
                            cert_arn=CERT_ARN
                            )
ecs_service_stack = RcsECSServiceStack(app, "RcsECSServiceStack", 
                   vpc_stack=vpc_stack, 
                   ecs_stack=ecs_stack,
                   elbv2_stack=elbv2_stack
                   )
```

- Elbv2Stack
  defines an ApplicationLoadbalancer with listener

  ```
    self.domain_cert = certm.Certificate.from_certificate_arn(
        self,
        "rcs-domain-cert",
        cert_arn
    )
    self.elbv2_loadbalancer = elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(
        self,
        "rcs-elastic-loadbalancer",
        load_balancer_name="rcs-elastic-loadbalancer",
        vpc=vpc_stack.vpc,
        vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(
            subnets=vpc_stack.vpc.public_subnets
        ),
        idle_timeout=Duration.seconds(300),
        internet_facing=True
    )
    self.elbv2_loadbalancer_listener = self.elbv2_loadbalancer.add_listener(
        "rcs-elastic-loadbalancer-listener",
        port=443,
        protocol=elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTPS,
        certificates=[elbv2.ListenerCertificate.from_certificate_manager(self.domain_cert)]
    )
    self.elbv2_loadbalancer_listener.add_targets(
        "rcs-default-target-group",
        port=80,
        protocol=elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP
    )
  ```
- EcsStack
  defines an ECS Container service

  ```
    # ... service definitions 

    elbv2_stack.elbv2_loadbalancer_listener.add_targets(
        "rcs-api-backend-loadbalancer-target",
        port=80,
        targets=[
            ecs_service_stack.ecs_api_backend.load_balancer_target(
                container_name="testService",
                container_port=someContainerPort
            )
        ]
    )
    self.test_target_group = elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(
        self,
        "rcs-api-backend-target-group",
        vpc=vpc_stack.vpc,
        port=80,
        protocol=elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
        health_check=elbv2.HealthCheck(
            healthy_http_codes="200-299",
            interval=Duration.seconds(20),
            path="/health-check",
            protocol=elbv2.Protocol.HTTP,
            timeout=Duration.seconds(5),
            healthy_threshold_count=2
        )
    )
    elbv2_stack.elbv2_loadbalancer_listener.add_action(
        "rcs-api-backend-elbv2-action",
        action=elbv2.ListenerAction.forward(
            target_groups=[self.test_target_group],
        ),
        priority=2,
        conditions=[
            elbv2.ListenerCondition.path_patterns(["*"])
        ]
    )
  ```

The Error:

```
RuntimeError: Error: 'RcsECSServiceStack' depends on 'RcsELBv2Stack' 
({RcsECSServiceStack/rcs-api-backend/Service}.addDependency({RcsELBv2Stack/rcs-elastic-loadbalancer/rcs-elastic-loadbalancer-listener/Resource}), 
{RcsECSServiceStack/rcs-api-backend/Service}.addDependency({RcsELBv2Stack/rcs-elastic-loadbalancer/rcs-elastic-loadbalancer-listener/rcs-default-target-groupGroup/Resource}), 
{RcsECSServiceStack/rcs-api-backend/Service}.addDependency({RcsELBv2Stack/rcs-elastic-loadbalancer/rcs-elastic-loadbalancer-listener/rcs-api-backend-loadbalancer-targetGroup/Resource}), 
{RcsECSServiceStack/rcs-api-backend/Service}.addDependency({RcsELBv2Stack/rcs-elastic-loadbalancer/rcs-elastic-loadbalancer-listener/rcs-api-backend-elbv2-actionRule/Resource})). Adding this dependency (RcsELBv2Stack -> RcsECSServiceStack/rcs-api-backend-target-group/Resource.Ref) would create a cyclic reference.
```

To have an overview, it would be great to define the container service with its target group in the dedicated stack, but I get a cyclic dependency if I do that.
Is it a problem with the action added?
Is there a possible solution to this?

Comment: What resources are causing the cyclic dependency?  What's the error message?

Comment: hi, i have edited the error into it :) thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our experience, we had to separate how we create an ECS service and a Load Balancer. We ended up having an ECS Service construct that can be deployed even without a load balancer and target group attached to it.

The ECS service construct we made have optional parameters to put in the load balancer ARN and the load balancer HTTPS listener ARN. We then use LookUps to reference those ALB and Listeners.

Comment: Thank you Francis :) that is what I came up with as well